# How to limit the effect of client modifications to production systems

Tags: postgresql, open-source, production-environment, resource-management

Our shop has developed a few WEB/SMS/DB solution for a dozen client installations. The applications have some real-time performance requirements, and are just good enough to function properly. The problem is that the clients (owners of the production servers) are using the same server/database for customizations that are causing problems with the performance of the applications that we created and deployed.

A few examples of clients' customizations:

- Adding large tables with many text datatypes for the columns that get cast to other data types in the queries
- No primary keys, indexes, or FK constraints
- Use of external scripts that use `count(*) from table where id = x`, in a loop from the script, to determine how to construct more queries later in the same script. (no bulk actions that the planner can optimize or just do everything in a single pass)
- All new code files on the server are created/owned by root, with 0777 permissions

The clients don't take suggestions/criticism well. If we just go ahead and try to port/change the scripts ourselves, the old code can come back, clobbering any changes that we make! Or with out limited knowledge of their use cases, we break functionality while trying to optimize their changes.

My question is this: how can we limit the resources to queries/applications other that what we create and deploy? Are there any pragmatic options in scenarios like this? We prided ourselves in having an OSS solution, but it seems that it's become a liability.

We use PG 8.3 running on a range on Linux Distos. The clients prefer php, but shell scripts, perl, python, and plpgsql are all used on the system in one form or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem started about two minutes after the first client was given full access to the first computer, and it hasn't gone away since.  Anytime someone whose priorities are getting business oriented work done quickly they will be sloppy about it and screw up things for everyone.  That's just how things work, because proper design and implementation are harder than cheap hacks.  You're not going to solve this problem, all you can do is figure out how to make it easier for the client to work with you than against you.  If you do it right, it will look like excellent service rather than nagging.

First off, the database side.  There's now way to control query resources in PostgreSQL.  The main difficulty is that tools like "nice" control CPU usage, but if the database doesn't fit in RAM it may very well be I/O usage that is killing you.  See this [developer message](http://markmail.org/message/zujp7a5ufevxsf2j?q=postgresql+%22change+query+priority%22&page=1&refer=zujp7a5ufevxsf2j#query:postgresql%20%22change%20query%20priority%22+page:1+mid:567ndqwlgl5td7pe+state:results) summarizing the issues here.

Now, if in fact it's CPU the clients are burning through, you can use two techniques to improve that situation:

- Install a C function that changes the process priority ([example 1](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2001-12/msg00214.php), [example 2](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=11)) and make sure whenever they run something it gets called first (maybe put it into their psql config file, there are other ways).
- Write a script that looks for postmaster processes spawned by their userid and renice them, make it run often in cron or as a daemon.

It sounds like your problem isn't the particular query processes they're running, but rather other modifications they're making to the larger structure.  There's only one way to cope with that:  you have to treat the client like they're an intruder and use the approaches of that portion of the computer security field to detect when they screw things up.  Seriously!  Install an intrusion detection system like Tripwire on the server (there are better tools, that's just the classic example), and have it alert you when they touch anything.  New file that's 0777?  Should jump right out of a proper IDS report.

On the database side, you can't directly detect the database being modified usefully.  You should do a pg_dump of the schema every day into a file (*pg_dumpall -g* and *pg_dump -s*, then diff that against the last one you delivered and again alert you when it's changed.  If you manage that this well, the contact with the client turns into "we noticed you changed  on the server...what is it you're trying to accomplish with that?" which makes you look like you're really paying attention to them.  That can turn into a sales opportunity, and they may stop fiddling with things as much just knowing you're going to catch it immediately.

The other thing you should start doing immediately is install as much version control software as you can on each client box.  You should be able to login to each system, run the appropriate status/diff tool for the install, and see what's changed.  Get that mailed to you regularly too.  Again, this works best if combined with something that dumps the schema as a component to what it manages.  Not enough people use serious version control approaches on the code that lives in the database.

That's the main set of technical approaches useful here.  The rest of what you've got is a classic consulting client management problem that's far more of a people problem than a computer one.  Cheer up, it could be worse--FSM help you if you give them ODBC access and they discover they can write their own queries in Access or something simple like that.